# ModuleNotFoundError for selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, module

I have the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from StringIO import StringIO
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import lxml.html
import time
import re
import requests
import argparse
import sys
import os.path
```

And this is the result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7TRm.jpg)

May you tell me how to fix this problem?

Another error appear after I solved the first.

```
ModuleNotFoundError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-36163cf9d0fe> in <module> 
6 from colorama import init
7 from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
----> 8 from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
9 import lxml.html
10 import time
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyvirtualdisplay'
```

Comment: Try `from io import StringIO`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from io import StringIO` works. If it does not, try to install it first with your terminal.